Setting up Custom Domains in Firebase App Hosting
I am trying to setup a custom domain (Squarespace) with Firebase App Hosting. But for some reason Firebase is not able to verify the CNAME records. It has been more than 24 hours since I added the records in DNS settings. Any hints on how can I debug this or fix this?

If you think your DNS is set up correctly, contact Firebase support for assistance.

I tried that but no response. It looks like the setup is stuck on verifying the acme challenge.

Found the issue apparently Squarespace automatically includes the domain name at the end of Host values, so it is not necessary to include them. Specially in the acme challenge, just removed the domain name from the end of the string and it was propagated successfully.
